# Page Break On ReportViewer make extra page when printed?

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, page-break

I'm using Report Viewer(VS 2008) to make a report in VB.net. I add Table with Table Header, Table Detail, and Table Footer. Then insert a Table Group(table1_group1) and add expression =IntRowNumber Nothing-1/10 on that group. I check page breaks at end.

When I load the report its show normal :

- page 1 : page header+ table header + table detail(10 list data) +
  page footer
- page 2 : page header+ table header + table detail(5 list data) +
  table footer + page footer

But when I click Print Layout Icon its show an extra page(page 3):

- page 1 : page header+ table header + table detail(10 list data) +
  page footer
- page 2 : page header+ table header + table detail(5 list data) + page
  footer
- page 3 : page header + table footer + page footer ( this is the
  error)

I also try to print the report and its print 3 page.
Can anyone help me solve this problem??

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem once:

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2010/07/22/unwanted-page-breaks-in-reportviewer.aspx

Comment: thank you for reply... but i thing thats not the problem. because i have tried before to move the data on Table footer to Table Group let say that data is Total Payment. Its show normal in report viewer and print layout view. but the report is showing Total Payment on all page. I want to show that data only on last page with page header, Table header, Table detail and Page footer.